# Classify any number into category ranges in Swift

Tags: swift, range

Is there a succinct structure or way of using ranges in Swift to classify any value of a range-compatible type (eg: Double) into discrete, user/programmer-defined categories?

eg: Someone might want to use temperatures in celsius to classify areas of earth.

- `..<-10` - Arctic
- `-10..<10` - Cold
- `10..<25` - Temperate
- `25...` - Hot

Given that a generic structure for this already exists, the programmer might write:

```
let temperatureClassifier = MagicClassifier<Int, String>(
    lowestCategory: "Arctic",
    aboveValueCategoryIs: [
        -10: "Cold",
        10: "Temperate",
        25: "Hot"
    ]
)

// ...more code...

print(temperatureClassifier.classify(12))
```

and expect the result "Temperate".

(This example is trivial with some if/else (or switch) blocks and static ranges like this, but if the user/programmer wanted to define many more categories the if/else strategy would become unwieldy, or if the number of categories were user-defined it could not be written out beforehand)

If possible, I would like to avoid optionals, and try-catch functions, as for these kinds of classifications there is no ambiguity. i.e. in `MagicClassifier` above, if the `aboveValueCategoryIs:` dictionary were to be empty (replaced with `[:]`), all values from `Int.min` to `Int.max` passed to `.classify(_:)` should return "Arctic".

Note: I am not necessarily asking for someone to write `MagicClassifier`; more checking there isn't a built-in for this that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in construct to to this, but it can be relatively achieved via a short generic function that could look like this:

```
func clasify<T, R>(value: T, with table: [(Range<T>,R)], defaultValue: R) -> R {
    return table.first { $0.0 ~= value }?.1 ?? defaultValue
}
```

which you can use it like this:

```
let temperatureMapping: [(Range<Int>, String)] = [
    (Int.min ..< -10, "Arctic"),
    (-10 ..< 10, "Cold"),
    (10 ..< 25, "Temperate"),
    (25 ..< Int.max, "Hot")]

let temperatureClass = clasify(value: 12, with: temperatureMapping, defaultValue: "Invalid")
// Temperate
```

If you're sure the lookup table is exhaustive you can drop the "defaultValue" argument and use force unwrap on `first`, however I would not recommend something like this.

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot neater than mine! I think I was accidentally asking two questions in one (a. how to build a mapping safely, b. how to classify against the mapping) and this is a great answer for 'b', thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've written my version of `MagicClassifier` below:

```
struct ClassifiableRange<Category, Value> where Value: Comparable, Value: Hashable {
    private let lowestCategory: Category
    private let lowestValueInRanges: Value?
    private let ranges: [ Range<Value> ]
    private let categoryDictionary: [ Value : Category ]
    private let highestCategory: Category

    init(lowestCategory: Category, aboveValueCategoryIs: [Value : Category]) {
        self.lowestCategory = lowestCategory
        var sortedKeys = aboveValueCategoryIs.keys.sorted()
        self.lowestValueInRanges = sortedKeys.removeFirst()
        self.highestCategory = sortedKeys.last.map({ aboveValueCategoryIs[$0]! }) ?? lowestCategory

        var ranges: [ Range<Value> ] = []
        if
            let lowestValueInRanges = self.lowestValueInRanges,
            !sortedKeys.isEmpty
        {
            var lowerBound = lowestValueInRanges
            for upperBoundExclusive in sortedKeys {
                ranges.append(lowerBound..<upperBoundExclusive)
                lowerBound = upperBoundExclusive
            }
        }
        self.ranges = ranges

        self.categoryDictionary = aboveValueCategoryIs
    }

    func classify(_ value: Value) -> Category {
        guard
            let lowestValueInRanges = self.lowestValueInRanges,
            value >= lowestValueInRanges // There is more than one category, AND the value is not in the lowest category
        else { return self.lowestCategory }

        for range in ranges {
            if range.contains(value) {
                return self.categoryDictionary[range.lowerBound]!
            }
        }

        return self.highestCategory
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let temperatureClassifier = ClassifiableRange<String, Int>(
    lowestCategory: "Arctic",
    aboveValueCategoryIs: [
        -10: "Cold",
        10: "Temperate",
        25: "Hot"
    ]
)

temperatureClassifier.classify(12) // Returns "Temperate"
```

but would still appreciate any built-in ways of doing the same thing.